# OpenNebula - How to set root password for guest OS image without using SSH Key?

Tags: ssh, passwords, ssh-keys, opennebula

The only why to access image imported from MarketPlace in OpenNebula is with the Publuc SSH Key., so, **is there any way to set a initial root password for Linux images without using SSH Key ?** (*USERNAME=, PASSWORD=, Work only for Windows images*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your replay, latest version of OpenNebula can set root password by many ways, i’m using the starter script with this one line command : `echo -e "123456\n123456" | passwd root`

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The images of Market Place have a password user by default. Look for the information that is given in the image of Market Place

Comment: not all images, tiny linux have one, but centos, ubuntu.. use only SSH key